# New to coding. Having trouble with an email form on my portfolio webpage

Tags: html, forms, webforms

I'm trying to make a form that will send a person's details to me in an email. I've been successful in getting the page to start a new email to the selected email address, but the input values from the form are not populating in the email. It's just empty.

Here is my code:

```
<form role="form" action="MAILTO: myemail@gmail.com">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name">
<br><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Phone" id="phone">
<br><br>
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email">
<br><br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I've googled this and asked for help on the forums for the program I'm using to learn, but no success. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right, but you were missing 2 things. 1 the method of the form, in this case method="post" and the inputs need a name not an id. Code is corrected below:

```
<form role="form" action="MAILTO: myemail@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">
<br><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Phone" name="phone">
<br><br>
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
<br><br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Also to make the email better formatted I have added an enctype.